# How to set background image using bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, background-image, bootstrap-5

I have been trying to set a background image for my website using bootstrap 5 but it is not showing

I use external CSS to set the background image but it is not working
The code is:

```
    body {
background-image: url(images/bgr.jpeg);
}
```

I will like to know what I can do to set the background image for my website correctly. Thanks

Comment: Could you post the minimal reproducable code so we can see what's going on?

Comment: There isn't enough information here to debug your problem. Odds are that either the URL is wrong (use the Network tab of your browser's developer tools to debug it) or another element is covering it up (debug by looking at the descendant elements in the Elements tab of your browser's developer tools).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add background image using inline CSS, I hope it's better out of external CSS

> for example

```
<container style="background-image: url(images/bgr.jpeg); width: 100%; height: 100vh; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
// your next code is here
</container>
```

Remember it, we don't need to use use `"images/bgr.jpeg" for our path` with have to use just path name `images/bgr.jpeg`

Also we can set `width: 100%; height: 100vh;` etc

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have try the inline css but I didn't specify the width and height. Maybe that is why it is displaying repeated images. I will give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to add class on body in html like this `<body class="bg">` then call it in css

```
.bg {background-image: url("images/bgr.jpeg");}
```